# How to use Service in android

Tags: android, service

I'm new in android. I want to Use some background process. So I decided to use service. Therefore I make a simple app to learn using. But app Stops.
In manifest I defined service.
 In log cat shows:

07-12 17:49:03.067: E/AndroidRuntime(3367): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.servicetest.service; no empty constructor

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button b;
private TextView tv;
private BroadcastReceiver br=new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tv.setText(arg1.getExtras().getString("s").toString());
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);     
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), service.class));
        }
    });
}

public class service extends IntentService {
public service(String name) {
    super(name);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stu
    intent.putExtra("s", "salam");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Service` should be in it's own Java file and declared in the Manifest.

Comment: I defined in manifest

Comment: <service android:name="com.example.servicetest.service"
            android:process=":service"
            ></service>

Comment: Don't use `android:procces` **unless you have to** by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception explicitly says : `no empty constructor`

You should add an empty constructor to your service. You should extract your service into a separate class and add a **default public constructor** to it:

```
public service() {
    super("MyService");
}
```

Additionally, you should register your `BroadcastReceiver` in `onResume` :

```
registerReceiver(br,new IntentFilter("event"));
```

And unregister it in `onPause`:

```
unregisterReceiver(br);
```

Now in your service in `onHandleIntent` send the broadcast:

```
Intent send = new Intent("event");
send.putExtra("s", "salam");
sendBroadcast(send);
```

Comment: Thanks, But now don't show "salam" String In text view. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Any `Context` descendant (`Activity`, `Service`, `Application`) bust be defined in it's own file.
I'm not sure though if you can define it as a public static inner class, but it's a bad practice anyway.

So in order to make it work, extract it to a java file, like `service.java` and define it in the `manifest`

```
<service android:name="com.example.servicetest.service"/>
```

Don't use `android:procces` attrubute **unless you have to** by design because it adds too much complexity.

Consider that by java conventions, the class names start with uppercase letters.

Also, as `Andrei Catinean` mentioned, you have to define an empty constructor.

```
public service() {
    super("Your service name");
}
```

Comment: I did that. I've service.java and Main_Activity.java seperate each other